# Hazelcast exception putting bool value into map

Tags: hazelcast

We started using Hazelcast a couple of months ago.  We recently began testing it in our production environments and are now seeing this exception about once a week:

> 2020-02-11 12:10:00,084
>   com.hazelcast.partition.NoDataMemberInClusterException: Target of
>   invocation cannot be found! Partition owner is null but partitions
>   can't be assigned since all nodes in the cluster are lite members.
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.PartitionInvocation.newTargetNullException(PartitionInvocation.java:90)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.initInvocationTarget(Invocation.java:269)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:556)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:534)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:236)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationBuilderImpl.invoke(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:59)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:467)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.putInternal(MapProxySupport.java:406)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:121)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:111)

This is from Hazelcast 4.0 GA released 2/4/20.  This also happened to us running 3.12.x versions.  We were hoping the exception would go away each time we upgraded to newer versions.

Our setup is very simple.  Hazelcast is running on a single server with tons of free memory and Java 8.  All we are doing is putting a true/false value into a map that only has a single integer key with a value of zero.  Really, this is like the smallest map possible!  The server runs fine for many days, but eventually this exception gets thrown from the map.put(0, bool).

Other portions of our code are heavily using Hazelcast's executors.  We have had no trouble with that so far.

We configure Hazelcast like so:

> ```
> config.setInstanceName(name);        
>
> config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
> config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
> config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
> config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);
> config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
> config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember(AppConfig.getConfigSetting("/config/server/ip_address"));
>
> hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
> ```

I can't find any information about this exception other than this: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/partition/NoDataMemberInClusterException.html

Hoping someone can help figure out how to fix this.  We expected Hazelcast's maps to be bullet-proof on a single server.

Comment: This exception suggests that there is no server available at the time of invocation. You can confirm that by looking for disconnection events/messages earlier in the log.

Comment: Do you work directly with the single cluster member in your code? Or do you use an additional lite member? Can you share the member(s) log files?

Comment: @wildnez We have Hazelcast logging configured to use Log4J at the ERROR level, but don't see anything logged other than the above exception.

Comment: @kwart our setup is as simple as possible, just a single server.  We are logging at the ERROR level, just the above exception is reported.

Comment: Disconnect events are not error messages, therefore they would not make it to your logs. Can you change the log levels to INFO and give this another go?

Comment: Agree with @wildnez, logs are important in your case. I went through the related source code and didn't discover anything suspicious. Do you think it's possible for you to prepare a reproducer and share it as a GitHub issue? Or at least describe more precisely the usage and your environment (OS, exact java version, ...). How your IMap calls look like? How many calls per time unit do you have? How many days it took to fail? Do the executors run in the same Hazelcast member? Is your application running standalone or e.g. as a web-app? Do you customize data structures config (e.g. MapStore used)?

Comment: You can use the bug-reporting on the following URL:  https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new/choose

The communication will be simpler there.

Comment: I see, you've already reported it in the GitHub issue - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/1665.

Comment: I am currently configuring all our server instances running hazelcast to log "all".  Will forward captured logs to the github thread when the exception happens again.  Will report any final resolution back here.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/16651

The issue was apparently due to running Hazelcast on an Amazon EC2 instance.  The config settings we used needed to be adjusted to define an outbound port range.  Our final working config settings are this:

```
com.hazelcast.config.Config config = new com.hazelcast.config.Config();

config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j");

String name = AppCluster.isWorkerServer ? "worker "+AppHTTP.getSystemDomainAndContext() : "master"; 

config.setInstanceName(name);        

config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(false);
config.setProperty("hazelcast.socket.bind.any", "false");

// The next line is a suggested workaround for running on Amazon AWS to avoid periodic hazelcast crashes
// https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/16651
config.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPortDefinition("30000-60000");

// Default value to use when a single server
String hazelcastIP = "127.0.0.1";
if (AppCluster.isWorkerServer || AppCluster.totalServers > 1)
{
    if (AppConfig.getConfigSetting("/config/server/ec2_private_ip").length() > 0)
    {
        // If clustered and in Amazon AWS, use the server's private IP address
        hazelcastIP = AppConfig.getConfigSetting("/config/server/ec2_private_ip");
    }
    else
    {
        // If clustered and not in Amazon AWS, use the server's public IP address
        hazelcastIP = AppConfig.getConfigSetting("/config/server/ip_address");
    }
}

config.getNetworkConfig().setPublicAddress(hazelcastIP);
config.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", hazelcastIP);

hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```